# Hartl tutorial chap. 9.3.3. pagination test fail

Tags: testing, pagination

I would appreciate any help why my test is failing. I am doing it based on Michael Hartl tutorial and I tried almost everything and read a lot of about it, but still clueless. 
Tahnks

My test:

describe "pagination" do

```
before(:all) do
  sign_in FactoryGirl.create(:user)
  30.times { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
  visit users_path
end

after(:all)  { User.delete_all }

it 'has the right div' do
  page.should have_selector('div.pagination')
end

it "should list each user" do
  User.paginate(page: 1).each do |user|
    expect{page}.to have_selector('li', text: user.username)
  end
end
```

My view:

```
<h1>Všichni uživatelé</h1>

<%= will_paginate %>
<ul class="users">
  <% @users.each do |user| %>
    <li>
      <%= gravatar_for user%>
      <%= link_to user.username, user %>
    </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>

<%= will_paginate(:renderer => BootstrapPagination::Rails)%>
```

My controller:

```
def index
 @users = User.paginate(page: params[:page])
end
```

My error:

```
 1) User pages index pagination should list each user
 Failure/Error: expect{page}.to have_selector('li', text: user.username)
   expected css "li" with text "Person 44" to return something
 # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:122:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'
 # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:121:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the line:

expect{page}.to have_selector('li', text: user.username)

Should be:

expect{page}.to have_selector('li', text: user.user.name)